# Cannot access Debian smb share from Windows 7 64

Tags: windows-7, samba, linux-networking, network-share

This is an old problem, an in my experience the connection between windows and samba is unstable and different for every implementation. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, often without any apparent logic.

Right now I have a Debian server with a simple samba share:

```
[mediadisken]
    path = /mnt/mediadisken
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = no
    public = no
```

I have two linux system users, both of which have been added to samba with
    smbpasswd -a frankh
    smbpasswd -a smbadmin

Listing the users, everything seems to be in order:

```
$sudo pdbedit -w -L
frankh:1001:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:2D8141C0E359DBCF9D8948BA154715B6:[U          ]:LCT-56E42E95:
smbadmin:1002:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:B5797194788F406F023865AE8FAAE318:[U          ]:LCT-56E42F02:
```

Still, I'm unable to connect to the share from Windows 7 64. I get the login, and enter the correct username and passord, and get "Access denied".

I've tried using just the username in windows, as well as SMBSERVERIP\username, both without success.

Where should I begin to troubleshoot this, which should've been straight-forward and easy?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the `/mnt/mediadisken` directory so that `frankh` and `smbadmin` have permissions to access it?

Comment: I even tried setting chmod a+rwx on the entire mounted folder. No help.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you haven't already, I'd first verify the samba share is accessible from another computer running linux.

   ```
   mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password> //1.2.3.4/sharename /mnt
   ```

Then verify it mounted it successfully.

2. For what it's worth I'd try the Samba config below; this was taken from a working production setup with samba share on centos 7, and windows users accessing with username and password.

   ```
   [global] 
   security = user
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   Map to guest = Bad User
   username map = /etc/samba/smbusers


   [mediadisken]
   path = /share
   valid users = frankh smbadmin
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   create mode = 0666
   directory mode = 0777
   oplocks = false
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Seems that the problem is with the samba server and not with Windows, at least. I cannot connect from the other Linux client (which I should've checked first). I also copied the config you posted, and restarted the server, but I still cannot connect - from Linux of Windows. The Linux error is mount error(13): permission denied.

Comment: I'd take a look here and double check your setup steps then, http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-setup-samba-server-with-tdbsam-backend.html